# Was Sun's distance mentioned correctly in "Hanuman Chalisa", the 16 th century poem?

Tags: religion, astronomy

I found many sites stating that the Sun's distance was mentioned accurately in the "Hanuman Chalisa" hymn written in the 16th century.

Even Wikipedia has a mention of this.

> juga sahasra jojana para bhānū।
>
> līlyo tāhi madhura phala jānū॥ 18 ॥
>
> The Surya, sun situated {1Yug=12000 years, 1Sahastra=1000, 1Yojan=8 Miles, (Yug x Sahastra x Yojan) =12000x1000x8miles =96000000 miles (1mile =1.6kms) 96000000 miles =96000000x1.6kms= 153600000 kms} 153600000 kms from the earth, was swallowed by you after you assumed him to be a sweet fruit.[56]

The question is what is yug?

Does yug equal to 12000 years.

Why is years used in distance?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman_Chalisa

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10370/did-our-ancestors-calculate-the-distance-between-prithvi-earth-and-surya-sun

Comment: This seems like a good start: http://www.thelogicguide.com/you-were-wrong-hanuman-chalisa/

Comment: In the mid 1600s, Huygens and Cassini independently calculated fairly accurate estimates of the distance to the Sun.  It's not amazingly unbelievable that someone else managed it a century earlier.  Whether the units are correctly converted, or were later adjusted to match the known value, is the real question.

Comment: @RayButterworth: I'm no astronomer, but I believe that Huygens and Cassini could estimate the distance to the sun by observing the changes of the the angular sizes of Mars and/or Venus during their solar rotations. These calculations became possible in the 17th century only because of the recent advances in optics to construct better and better telescopes. If someone did the same feast at a time that precedes even the invention of the telescope, that would be an amazing feat indeed.

Comment: @Schmuddi, Cassini used the parallax of Mars, which doesn't require a good telescope, but does require Kepler's laws of planetary motion.